# I need to create php class from xsd file not able to create via xsd2php

Tags: xsd

XSD File:
xsd2php shows below error-
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder' not found in /var/www/html/xsd2php-master/bin/xsd2php:19

```
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="4.001" id="OTA2008B">
 <xs:include schemaLocation="OTA_HotelReservation.xsd"/>
 <xs:annotation>
  <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">All Schema files in the OTA specification are made available according to the terms defined by the OTA License Agreement at http://www.opentravel.org/Specifications/Default.aspx</xs:documentation>
 </xs:annotation>
 <xs:element name="OTA_HotelResNotifRQ">
  <xs:annotation>
   <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Hotel Reservation Notif Request supports the functionality of updating other systems with reservation data. The message assumes a push model, with the originating system pushing the data to another system.  The originating system would usually be a booking source, such as a Global Distribution System (GDS), a Central Reservation System (CRS) or some other agent of the hotel.</xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="POS" type="POS_Type" minOccurs="0">
     <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">The point-of-sale data, contained in the element, communicates the information that allows the receiving system to identify the trading partner that is sending the request or the response message.  </xs:documentation>
     </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="MessageID" type="UniqueID_Type" minOccurs="0">
     <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">This represents a batch ID.</xs:documentation>
     </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="HotelReservations" type="HotelReservationsType" minOccurs="0"/>
   </xs:sequence>
   <xs:attributeGroup ref="OTA_PayloadStdAttributes"/>
   <xs:attribute name="ResStatus" type="TransactionActionType" use="optional"/>
   <xs:attribute name="HoldDuration" type="xs:duration" use="optional">
    <xs:annotation>
     <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">The time until a hold is released.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
   </xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just add this line at the begining of file

```````

The result in the file

```
<?php
/**
 * Generated by XSD2PHP
 *
 * PHP version 5.3
 *
 * @category Util
 * @package  XSD2PHP
 * @author   Ariel Garcia<ags@leirags.com>
 * @license  GNU GPL - http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.txt
 * @link     https://github.com/davidgillen/XSD2PHP
 */

/**
 * Class representing a OTA_HotelResNotifRQ
 *
 * @category XSD2PHP
 * @package  XSD2PHP
 * @author   Ariel Garcia<ags@leirags.com>
 * @license  GNU GPL - http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.txt
 * @link     https://github.com/davidgillen/XSD2PHP
 */
class OTA_HotelResNotifRQ
{
    public $POS;
    public $MessageID;
    public $HotelReservations;

    /**
     * OTA_HotelResNotifRQ constructor
     *
     * @param POS_Type              $POS               {0, 1} Optional The point-of-sale data, contained in the element, communicates the information that allows the receiving system to identify the trading partner that is sending the request or the response message.
     * @param UniqueID_Type         $MessageID         {0, 1} Optional This represents a batch ID.
     * @param HotelReservationsType $HotelReservations {0, 1} Optional
     */
    public function __construct($POS = null, $MessageID = null, $HotelReservations = null)
    {
        if ( $POS == null ) {
            // Do nothing, $minOccurs is 0
        } else {
            if ( get_class($POS) != 'POS_Type' ) {
                throw new Exception('$POS must be of type POS_Type.');
            }
            $this->POS = $POS;
    
        }
        if ( $MessageID == null ) {
            // Do nothing, $minOccurs is 0
        } else {
            if ( get_class($MessageID) != 'UniqueID_Type' ) {
                throw new Exception('$MessageID must be of type UniqueID_Type.');
            }
            $this->MessageID = $MessageID;
    
        }
        if ( $HotelReservations == null ) {
            // Do nothing, $minOccurs is 0
        } else {
            if ( get_class($HotelReservations) != 'HotelReservationsType' ) {
                throw new Exception('$HotelReservations must be of type HotelReservationsType.');
            }
            $this->HotelReservations = $HotelReservations;
    
        }
    }
}
```

I hope is usefull to you.